# How to give access to my api for a mobile app?

Tags: ios, laravel, api, security, passport.js

i have to develop the backend of a mobile app (IOS swift). I started to create the api with laravel.
But i'm concerned about the access to my api: how i should i give access to my api ? i've heard some stuff about Oauth key and passport .

For my app i want to :

```
-user can create an account (i guess it's with JWT)
-user can navigate in my app and start to use it after they create their account.
```

I wan't know the basic process about creating an api for a private use (only my app will use it) what security stuff should i implement and how the account creation for my app will work. Thx :)

Comment: I'd encourage you to read the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## PRIVATE APIs

> wan't know the basic process about creating an api for a private use (only my app will use it)

Let me tell you here a cruel truth...

No matter if an API doesn't have public accessible documentation or if is is protected by any kind of secret or authentication mechanisms, once is accessible from the internet is not private any-more.

So you can make it hard to find and access, but to truly lock it to your mobile app you will gonna have an hard time to do it so.

## WHO AND WHAT IS ACCESSING THE API SERVER

The **WHO** is the user of the mobile app that you can authenticate,authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID or OAUTH2 flows.

Now you need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling your API server and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server, is it really your genuine mobile app or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around your API server with a tool like Postman?

Well to identify the **WHAT** developers tend to resort to an API key that usually they hard-code in the code of their mobile app and some go the extra mile and compute it at run-time in the mobile app, thus becomes a dynamic secret in opposition to the former approach that is a static secret embedded in the code.

## REVERSE ENGINEERING A MOBILE APP BINARY IS EASY

The truth is that anything running in the client side can be reverse engineered
easily by an attacker on a device he controls. He will use introspection frameworks like [Frida](https://www.frida.re/) or [xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) to intercept at runtime the running code of the mobile app or will use a proxy tool like [MiTM Proxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/) for watching the communications between the mobile app and the API server. Normally their first step in reverse engineer a mobile app will be to use the [Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF) to reverse engineer the binary of you mobile app to extract all static secrets and to identify attack vectors.

[Mobile Security Framework](https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF)

> Mobile Security Framework is an automated, all-in-one mobile application (Android/iOS/Windows) pen-testing framework capable of performing static analysis, dynamic analysis, malware analysis and web API testing.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

[xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too much). It's also easy to undo.

[MiTM Proxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/)

> An interactive TLS-capable intercepting HTTP proxy for penetration testers and software developers.

So now what... Am I doomed to the point I cannot protect my API server from being abused??? No quiet so... hope still exists!!!

## A POSSIBLE SOLUTION

So anything that runs on the client side and needs some secret to access an API can be abused in different ways and you can learn more on [this series](https://blog.approov.io/tag/a-series-mobile-api-security) of articles about Mobile API Security Techniques. This articles will teach you how API Keys, User Access Tokens, HMAC and TLS Pinning can be used to protect the API and how they can be bypassed.

> But i'm concerned about the access to my api: how i should i give access to my api ? i've heard some stuff about Oauth key and passport .
>
> For my app i want to :
>
> -user can create an account (i guess it's with JWT)
> -user can navigate in my app and start to use it after they create their account.
>
> ...and how the account creation for my app will work.

Laravel Passport is an OAUTH2 server thus is a good solution to use for user creation and identification, thus to solve the problem of **WHO** is using your mobile app and API server.

> what security stuff should i implement

To solve the problem of **WHAT** is accessing your mobile app you need to use one or all the solutions mentioned in the series of articles about Mobile API Security Techniques that I mentioned above and accepted that they can only make unauthorized access to your API server harder to bypass but not impossible.

A better solution can be employed by using a Mobile App Attestation solution that will enable the API server to know is receiving only requests from a genuine mobile app.

### Mobile App Attestation

Use a Mobile App Attestation solution to enable the API server to know **WHAT** is sending the requests, thus enabling it to only respond to requests from a genuine mobile app.

The role of a Mobile App Attestation service is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered or is not running in a rooted device by running a SDK in the background that will communicate with a service running in the cloud to attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

Now the App must sent with every API call the JWT token in the headers of the request. This will allow the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

The Mobile App Attestation service already exists as a SAAS solution at Approov(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS, Android, React Native and others. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token issued by the cloud service. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.

Comment: Thanks a lot man i didn't expect a such well explained answer, i appreciate !
I guess it's the same problem if i want to create a SPA ?

Comment: SPA's are even easier to reverse engineer, but the API server will have the same issues to trust in **WHO** and **WHAT** is performing the request.